# Does Collatz mapping define Markov homogeneous chain?

Tags: probability-theory

In [van Douwen, Eric K. (1992).Finitely additive measures on ${\bf N}$.Topology Appl.47(3) 223--268.] has been constructed a finitely additive probability measure $P$ defined on the power set ${\mathcal{P}}({N})$ such that if $Y$ is obtained
from $X$ by a process which makes sets $r$ times as small, from an intuitive point of view, then $P(Y) = r^{-1}P(X)$ for all $X, Y \in {\mathcal{P}}({N})$.

In the sequel,  under  a probability space  $(\Omega,{\mathcal{F}},P)$~  we will assume a triplet  $({N}, {\mathcal{P}}({N}), P)$.

In modular arithmetic notation, define the random variable(Collatz mapping)  $\xi$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
\xi(\omega) = \begin{cases} \omega/2 &\text{if } \omega \equiv 0 \pmod{2}\\ 3\omega+1 & \text{if } \omega \equiv 1 \pmod{2} .\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Let $\xi_n(\omega)$ be  $\xi$  applied to $\omega$  recursively $n$ times ;  Clearly, the chain of
logical transitions
\begin{equation}
\xi_0(\omega) \to \xi_1(\omega) \to \cdots ~~(\omega \in \Omega)
\end{equation}
depends on the chance factor, where $\xi_0(\omega)=\omega$ and  $\xi_1=\xi$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$.

The sequence $(\xi_{n}(\omega))_{n \in {N}}$ is called a Collatz sequence starting at point $\omega$.

We say that a system $\xi_n(\omega)$ is in a position $\epsilon_0$ (and write $\xi_n(\omega) \in \epsilon_0$ if $\xi_n(\omega)\equiv 0 \pmod{2}$
and $\xi_n(\omega)$ is in a position $\epsilon_1$ (and write $\xi_n(\omega) \in \epsilon_1$) if  $\xi_n(\omega)\equiv 1\pmod{2}$. Hence we have
a system, which after each step
changes its  position and a set of possible
positions are $\{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1 \}$.

My question is the following: Is $(\xi_n)_{n \in N}$ Markov  homogeneous chain with respect to positions  $\{\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1 \}$ ?